# Pre-fill content, title and custom fields to new posts (with custom post-type) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to pre-fill new posts (with specific custom post-type) every time I press ADD NEW in Wordpress Admin Panel?

Because now a days I use a posts with pre-filled stuff and every time I need to add a new posts, I duplicate this older one. But this is not as fast as just pressing ADD NEW and having everything pre-filled.

Maybe is there a way to fill all content I want (texts, select box, custom fields...) as soon as I press ADD NEW? Even fill POST_ID in a custom field.

I tried to use this one but I was only capable of filling custom field, maybe someone can help me expand its limit and fill all the post :D.

```
function my_editor_content( $content, $post ) {
if ($post->post_type == property) {
$content = 'your content';
        }
        return $content;
    }
```

I'm even using this one to simplify, but I need to copy everytime and paste the same code. And I have no clue how to fill custom fields and to select custom taxonomy too.

```
add_filter( 'default_title', 'my_editor_title' );
function my_editor_title( $title ){
    $title = 'Default Title';
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly. Look on these filter hook- [wp_insert_post_data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data). In `functions.php`:

```
 if (isAdmin()){

    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','custom_insert_post', '99', 2);

    function custom_insert_post($data, $postarr){ <-- 
        $data['post_title'] = 'default_post_title';
        $data['post_status'] = 'future'; 
        //.... etc            


    }


 }
```

Also look on that hook - [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

```
 add_action('save_post', 'custom_insert_meta_values');

 function custom_insert_meta_values($post_ID){
   $default_meta_key = '....';
   $default_meta_value = '....';

   add_post_meta($post_ID, $default_meta_key, $default_meta_value);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not allow to insert data to custom fields.

Comment: @Diego Why not? Just, use both hooks.

Comment: I'll try it in Monday. Thanks!

Comment: Just copying and pasting your code didn't work. Now I'm reading the manual to see what is wrong. And sorry for the late response, I was working  on a new server (webmin) and totally forget about this wordpress "issue".